# Expand jQuery unobtrusive options

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using jquery.validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.

I want to show an alert when my form is invalid.

jquery.validate has the validate() method, which takes in an options parameter. There I could set the `invalidHandler` handler.
See also: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#invalidhandler

However there does not seem to be any (straight forward) way to expand the options .unobtrusive is passing to the validate() method.

What would be the best way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I got now. Maybe there are other solutions, but this works.

```
$("#my-form").bind("invalid-form", function (form, validator) {

    var firstError = validator.errorList[0];
    alert(firstError.message);
});
```